# Shell Script to print recordId having maximum execution time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Given a log file as below, which could have 100s of records like this, we need to find the recordId using shell script which has the highest execution time:

file example

```
recordid=11   
time=123ms   
date=today   

recordid=12   
time=11ms    
date=yesterday

recordid=13  
time=800ms  
date=yesterday2   

recordid=14   
time=22ms    
date=today2
```

Thanks in advance!
Piyush

Comment: You could: first convert it to TSV like file. Read 4 lines and remove the parts before `=` and output them with tabs between. You could do it in `awk`, `bash`, `sed`. Once you have TSV-ish format, it's trivial - sort numerically on 2nd column and output first/last line.

Comment: do you need *just* a recordid OR the whole record?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
cat records |
cut -d '=' -f 2 |                            # ignore keys, just need values
tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/##/\n/g' | tr -d '#' |  # make records lines
tr -s ' ' |                                  # regularize lines
sed 's/ms//' |                               # don't need the units
sort -k 2 -n |                               # sort by second column as a number
tail -n 1 |                                  # get the last, i.e., highest
cut -d ' ' -f1                               # get the first value, i.e., the ID
```

Comment: Side note, pro tip: `|` ignores following newlines and comments, you do not need '\' on the of line, and your multiline version may just work, just replace `--` for `#` for comments and add `|` on the end of commands. [repl bash](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PoliteLoyalCensorware#main.sh)

Answer (score 2):

if you're into "pipes":

```sh
cut -d= -f2 file | awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=, | sort -t ',' -k2n,2 | tail -1 | cut -d, -f1
```

Comment: thank you very much @vgersh99 , can you help me understand the significance of ,2 in -k2n,2

Comment: `-k2n,2` - `2` <starting at key 2> `n` <numerically> `.2` <ending at key 2>

Answer (score 2):

Using an empty `RS` you can do it easily:

```
awk -F= -v RS= '$3 == "time" && max < ($4+0){max = ($4+0); s=$0} END{print s}' file
```

```
recordid=13
time=800ms
date=yesterday2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following written with shown samples. Written and tested it on
https://ideone.com/LA9pDU#stdin

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/ +$/,"")
}
/time/{
  gsub(/.*=|ms/,"")
  recordMax=(max>$0?recordMax:prev)
  max=(max>$0?max:$0)
}
/recordid/{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(max && recordMax){
     print recordMax,max
  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: In case you don't need the max value then you could remove `max` in `END` block statement and it will only print maximum time taking recordid only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= 'substr($2,6)+0>max {max=substr($2,6)+0; s=$0} END {print s}' file
```

Output:

```
recordid=13  
time=800ms  
date=yesterday2
```

- Input file has one record per paragraph, we state that with `RS=`
- That `substr()` of the second field will be like `800ms`, so to get only the numerical value, we use `+0`.

Note that your records should have all times in ms, or else you have to check not only the number, but the units too.